# PowerShell strips recursive variable of its full path

Tags: powershell, recursion, get-childitem

I have a simple script that walks a directory tree.

```
function GetSubFolders([IO.DirectoryInfo]$folder) {
    Write-Host "Getting folder $folder"

    Get-ChildItem $folder | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { GetSubFolders $_ }
}
```

If I call `GetSubFolders "c:\temp"`, it fails for every subdirectory found in c:\temp:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\somefolder

Where "somefolder" is a subdirectory of c:\temp.  The variable `$_` is clearly a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object, but why is it stripped of its absolute path and suddenly made relative to the current directory, c:\windows\system32?  Note that upon entry into this method it correctly outputs

> Getting folder c:\temp

Which means it works once, so it's can't be an issue with `Get-ChildItem` accepting a `DirectoryInfo` object as a parameter.

Comment: you have tried to use an object "by name" or "by position" that ONLY matches the `-Name` property of `Get-ChildItem.` [*grin*] take a look at this `[io.directoryinfo]'C:\temp' | Select-Object -Property *` and then compare it to the list from this `(Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter *).Name`. note the lack of any `-Path` or -LiteralPath` property name in the 1st object.

Comment: Why does it work once, then, is why I'm puzzled.

Comment: i don't know ... it always seems to fail for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp' -Recurse -Directory
```

The directory flag will be available in V3. If you are not using V3 you can also use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp' -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

#### Edit:

Directory flag is available in V3.
Thank You Ansgar Wiechers for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetSubFolders([IO.DirectoryInfo]$folder) {
    Write-Host "Getting folder $folder"
    Get-ChildItem $folder | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { GetSubFolders $_.FullName }
}
```

I think you're looking for the property `FullName`.

Comment: This is what I had used as a work around, but if $_ is a directoryinfo object, why is .FullName even required?

Comment: powershell working with objects. Every object have more than 1 property (usually). So some of them should return one of it (property) as default value in specific scenarios like yours. Default value in your case would be name but not fullname.

Comment: Other way as your construction may work use $folder.fullname at the beginning instead of $_.fullname at the end

Comment: 1 other way: (gci $folder -recurse | where {$_.mode -like 'd*'}).fullname | sort

Answer (score 0):

The solution with recursion/pipes is pretty inefficient. As other suggested better use -recurse switch with GCI. But there is also an alternative with loop/queue. This will work for any kind of tree object - loop through children of the root node, and if a child has more nodes - add it to the queue.

```
function Get-SubfolderQueue { param([IO.directoryinfo]$dir)

 $queue = New-Object System.Collections.Queue
 $queue.Enqueue($dir)

 While($queue.Count -gt 0) {
    $curr = $queue.Dequeue()
    foreach ($d in $curr.GetDirectories()) {
        Write-Output $d
        If($d.GetDirectories().Count -gt 0) { 
           $queue.Enqueue($d)
         }
    }
 }

}
```